# Turning a .vbox file into a .vdi file

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vdi

How do I turn a `.vbox` file into a `.vdi` file?

When I look up my virtual machine in the explorer, it shows me a path to a folder, where only one `.vbox` file lays. I want to share the VirtualMachine with others, but as far as I can tell, I have to give them the `.vdi` file, right?

I tried to look it up on Google, but did not find anything related.

Answer (score 0):

The `.vbox` file is a settings file. It cannot be converted into a `.vdi` file. The `.vdi` 
 file is usually stored with .vbox file in `$HOME/VirtualBox VMs/Example VM/` (see e.g. [Where does virtualbox store installed applications?](https://superuser.com/questions/749639/where-does-virtualbox-store-installed-applications/749647))

If the `.vdi` file isn't there, right click your VM and go to Settings>Storage and find the path where it is stored.

An alternative way of sharing your machine is to go to Machine>Export to OCI.